# Sequelize query OR on association attribute and root attribute

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to execute a query where the OR statement references both a root table attribute and an associated table attribute. I tried the following which fails because SQL cannot access an alias across the entire query scope:

```
const group = await SocialGroup.findOne({
    attributes: ['id'],
    where: {
        id: {
            [Op.eq]: id,
        },
        [Op.or]: [
            {
                adminId: {
                    [Op.eq]: ctx.socialUser.id,
                },
            },
            {
                ['$roles.userId$']: {
                    [Op.eq]: ctx.socialUser.id,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.SocialGroupRight,
            as: 'roles',
            required: false,
        },
    ],
});
```

The error message is `Unknown column 'roles.userId' in 'where clause`. It does generate the query.

I use sequelize 4.x latest

Comment: in the generated query, what alias does Sequelize give to models.SocialGroupRight ?

Comment: `roles` 

```
`SocialGroup` WHERE (`SocialGroup`.`adminId` = '1776fdd6-b4d6-4b13-b2f3-21c0ec8add72' OR `roles`.`userId` = '1776fdd6-b4d6-4b13-b2f3-21c0ec8add72') AND `SocialGroup`.`id` = 'fb38ef26-31fe-41ca-925e-0c94eab33821' LIMIT 1) AS `SocialGroup` LEFT OUTER JOIN `SocialGroupRights` AS `roles` ON `SocialGroup`.`id` = `roles`.`groupId`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the findOne() method.  Testing a similar query, using findAll() gives this SQL, which works fine:

`SELECT ...
FROM sg
LEFT OUTER JOIN sgr
ON sg.id = sgr.sg_id
WHERE (sg.id = 1 OR sgr.name = 'hello');`

But changing to findOne() gives this invalid SQL:

`SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT ...
    FROM sg
    WHERE (sg.id = 1 OR sgr.name = 'hello') 
    LIMIT 1
    ) AS xxx
LEFT OUTER JOIN sgr 
ON sg.id = sgr.sg_id;`

The WHERE clause and LIMIT keywords are applied **BEFORE** the join, which busts the query.   FWIW, using findAll() with `limit: 1` did the same thing.

Sorry I don't have a more helpful answer....